# Update Time part of DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I want to update the time part of my datetime field in SQL.
I have an attendance table wherein the User can update the time depending on which attendance date he/she picks. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..myDate is the field name in the table. I used variables to save time values. Please let me know if you need any clarification.

```
declare @TestTime datetime
declare @hour int=10
declare @min int=10
declare @sec int=12
select @TestTime = cast(convert(varchar(100),myDate,101)+' 00:00:00' as datetime) from      TestTable
select dateadd(ss,@sec,dateadd(m,@min,dateadd(hh,@hour,@TestTime)))
```

Comment: I have these fields: Date, Time In, Time Out, UserID. How can I apply that? :) @HardCoreProgrammer

Comment: We can simplify it further in case if you are trying to achieve it in single query

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.. i can suggest the changes you can do to accomplish it.

Comment: UPDATE tblAttendance2 
    SET DateTimeIn = CONVERT(varchar(10),DateTimeIn, 120) + TimeInChange,
    DateTimeOut = CONVERT(varchar(10),DateTimeIn, 120) + TimeOutChange
    WHERE AttendanceDeductionsID = AttendanceDeductionsID @HardCoreProgrammer

Comment: By assuming TimeInChange and TimeOutChange are of type varchar (in format hh:mm:ss) and DateTimeIn and DateTimeOut are of type datetime, below query should work.

`UPDATE tblAttendance2 SET DateTimeIn = CAST((CONVERT(varchar(50),DateTimeIn, 101) + ' '+TimeInChange) AS DATETIME), DateTimeOut = CAST((CONVERT(varchar(50),DateTimeIn, 101) + ' '+ TimeOutChange) AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(CAST(MyDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Or this

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

or this

```
UPDATE tblAttendance2 
SET DateTimeIn = DateTimeIn + cast(@TimeInChange as DateTime),
DateTimeOut =DateTimeIn + cast(@TimeOutChange as DateTime)
WHERE AttendanceDeductionsID = @AttendanceDeductionsID
```