# Update time part only of a datetime column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
UPDATE tblAttendance2 
SET 
    DateTimeIn = CONVERT(varchar(10), DateTimeIn, 120) + @TimeInChange,
    DateTimeOut = CONVERT(varchar(10), DateTimeIn, 120) + @TimeOutChange
WHERE 
    AttendanceDeductionsID = @AttendanceDeductionsID
```

I'm getting this error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_UpdateDTR_TimeChange, Line 8
>   The data types varchar and time are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Time part of DateTime in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019345/update-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You are converting DateTimeIn to a varchar() and then adding @TimeInChange (which is probably a Time type). That doesn't work.

If DateTimeIn is type DateTime and @TimeInChange is type Time then this will work:

```
UPDATE tblAttendance2 
SET DateTimeIn = DateTimeIn + cast(@TimeInChange as DateTime),
DateTimeOut =DateTimeIn + cast(@TimeOutChange as DateTime)
WHERE AttendanceDeductionsID = @AttendanceDeductionsID
```

Comment: What does the TimeInChange and TimeOutChange accept? hh:mm:ss ? cause hh:mm won't work :( @yuser2970362

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@timeInChange` is of datatype `time` try this

```
UPDATE tblAttendance2 
SET 
    DateTimeIn  = cast(cast( DateTimeIn as date) as datetime) +  cast (@TimeInChange as datetime),
    DateTimeOut = cast(cast( DateTimeIn as date) as datetime)  + cast (@TimeOutChange as datetime)
WHERE 
    AttendanceDeductionsID = @AttendanceDeductionsID
```

Comment: I keep on getting this error, Incorrect syntax near ':'.
I input these values -- TimeInChange = '8:00', TimeOutChange '17:00' what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user2612969 what is the datatype of TimeInChange

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

`Sql Server` if you need only the hh+mm, then you can

```
--DECLARE @datetimein datetime

--SELECT @datetime = GETDATE()



UPDATE tblAttendance2 
SET DateTimeIn =
 CAST(DATEPART(hour, @datetimein) as varchar(2)) + 
':' +  CAST(DATEPART(minute, @datetimein)as varchar(2)) +@TimeInChange,

Date time out =use same procedure as above + @timeoutchange

  where <some condition condition>
```